# One insert kills Recursion in drools

Tags: recursion, insert, drools

This is related to my previous question. if I don't have the `insert`, it goes into a recursive loop as expected. But if I do have the `insert` the program ends. What am I missing here?

```
rule "Recurse"
    when
        f : Fibonacci(value == 0)
        not Fibonacci(sequence == 0)
    then
        System.out.println(f.sequence + "/" + f.value);
        insert(new Fibonacci(f.sequence - 1));
        f.value = 0;
        update(f);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of explaining this example, lets assume:

- there is only one rule in the system
- that the initial fact set provided to the rule engine meets the criteria of the when in that rule
- that sequence is a positive integer value

Firstly, we consider the case where the insert is commented out:

We know that the Working Memory contains at least one object that has value == 0 and there are no objects that have sequence == 0. (I find the more verbose form of not slightly more legible, you can replace not Fibonacci (...) with not ( exists Fibonacci(...))). Note that the rule is valid if there is a single object that meets both criteria.

The consequence sets the object's value to zero and notifies the engine that this object has changed. An infinite loop is then encountered as there is no object in the system with sequence == 0 and we've set the value to be such that this object will trigger the rule to fire.

Now, lets consider the case where the insert is uncommented:

We already know that the initial fact set fires the rule at least once. The consequence is that now an object is placed in working memory which has a decremented sequence and the object referenced by f has its value set to zero (it isn't changed from zero) and updated. There is a mechanism in place by which the end conditions are met, since now, at some point there will be an object inserted that has a zero sequence. That meets the end condition.

In short: the engine will exit when there is a Fibonacci object with sequence zero in it.

I, err.., think that this system might need a little bit of changing before it will output the Fibonacci sequence. You need a way to reference the previous two Fibonacci numbers to evaluate the one being set, the recursive method is much more elegent ;)